# MySQL: Does LIMIT reduce the number of calls to user-defined functions?

Tags: mysql, limit, user-defined-functions, database-performance

I have a computationally expensive user-defined function that I need to use against a large dataset. I don't sort nor ask for row-count (no FOUND_ROWS). If I specify LIMIT as part of the query, does MYSQL engine actually stop calling the function after getting the LIMIT-rows or does it run the function against the entire dataset regardless? Example:

```
select cols, .. where fingerprint_match(col, arg) > score  limit 5;
```

Ideally, fingerprint_match would be called as few as 5 times if first (random) rows resulted in a passing score.

Comment: Beware that, whilst the first 5 rows are **indeterminate**, they are not **random**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented under [Optimizing `LIMIT` Queries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/limit-optimization.html):

> MySQL sometimes optimizes a query that has a `LIMIT row_count` clause and no `HAVING` clause:
>
> ```
> [ deletia ]
> ```
>
> - As soon as MySQL has sent the required number of rows to the client, it aborts the query unless you are using `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`.

Comment: Also note that currently `EXPLAIN` doesn't show the `LIMIT` optimization. You'll need to time it to confirm and use `SQL_NO_CACHE` to prevent the query cache from affecting your tests.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the query will stop processing as soon as the specified number of matches are found but **ONLY IF there is no ORDER BY clause**. Otherwise it must find and sort all matches before applying the limit.

The only evidence I have for this is the statement in the docs that `"LIMIT 0 quickly returns an empty set. This can be useful for checking the validity of a query."`. This suggests to me that it doesn't bother applying the where clause to any rows once the limit has already been satisfied.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/limit-optimization.html

Comment: Not necessarily.  For example, if the sort can be resolved using an index, MySQL might be able to readily identify the rows that are to be returned without inspecting all matches.

Comment: Fair point regarding indexes. But this question pertains to user-defined functions so I assume that indexes are not readily available.